# How to select a dropdown menu item using Facebook Webdriver/ Selenium php

Tags: php, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am creating an automated script to do some functional testing for a website. The site, unfortunately, lacks id's and name's in the html, so I am left to use xpath and cssSelector. I am trying to select an option from a dropdown menu,and the program clicks on the dropdown menu box, but does not click on the option I am trying to choose. Here is an example of the function in my code.

```
$this->webDriver->wait(100)->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
        WebDriverBy::xpath('/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/input')));
    $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/select/option[2]'))->click();
    $this->goToApp();
```

I've looked and have seen similar post, but to no avail.

Comment: No, I am automating testing for a private website. I am trying to increase my code coverage.

Comment: There was a bug on the actual webpage which 'ate' my command. Once I fixed that, the program started working fine.